# Label faces and edges in a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

Is it possible to label the faces/edges of a drawing without specifying additional invisible nodes at the locations where we want labels? The code I'm currently working with is copied below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{freetikz}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main,foreground,background}

\def\thickness{0.7pt}

\tikzstyle{dot}=[circle, draw=black, fill=black!25, inner sep=.4ex, line width=\thickness, node on layer=foreground]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=black!50]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=gray!40!white]
\tikzstyle{whitedot}=[dot, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{reddot}=[dot, fill=red]
\tikzstyle{greendot}=[dot, fill=green]

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \gdef\node@@on@layer{%
  \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\pgfonlayer{#1}\unhbox\tikz@tempbox\endpgfonlayer\egroup}
\aftergroup\node@on@layer
  },
  /tikz/end node on layer/.code={
    \endpgfonlayer\endgroup\endgroup
  }
}
\def\node@on@layer{\aftergroup\node@@on@layer}
\makeatother

% Lengths
\newlength\morphismheight
\setlength\morphismheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimummorphismwidth
\setlength\minimummorphismwidth{0.6cm}
\newlength\stateheight
\setlength\stateheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimumstatewidth
\setlength\minimumstatewidth{0.89cm}
\newlength\connectheight
\setlength\connectheight{0.5cm}
\tikzset{width/.initial=\minimummorphismwidth}

% Keys
\newif\ifwedge\pgfkeys{/tikz/wedge/.is if=wedge}
\tikzset{wedge}
\newif\ifvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/vflip/.is if=vflip}
\newif\ifhflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hflip/.is if=hflip}
\newif\ifhvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hvflip/.is if=hvflip}
\newif\ifconnectnw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw/.is if=connectnw}
\newif\ifconnectne\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne/.is if=connectne}
\newif\ifconnectsw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw/.is if=connectsw}
\newif\ifconnectse\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se/.is if=connectse}
\newif\ifconnectn\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n/.is if=connectn}
\newif\ifconnects\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s/.is if=connects}
\newif\ifconnectnwf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw >/.is if=connectnwf}
\newif\ifconnectnef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne >/.is if=connectnef}
\newif\ifconnectswf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw >/.is if=connectswf}
\newif\ifconnectsef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se >/.is if=connectsef}
\newif\ifconnectnf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n >/.is if=connectnf}
\newif\ifconnectsf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s >/.is if=connectsf}
\newif\ifconnectnwr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw </.is if=connectnwr}
\newif\ifconnectner\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne </.is if=connectner}
\newif\ifconnectswr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw </.is if=connectswr}
\newif\ifconnectser\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se </.is if=connectser}
\newif\ifconnectnr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n </.is if=connectnr}
\newif\ifconnectsr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s </.is if=connectsr}
\tikzset{keylengthnw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthn/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthne/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthsw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengths/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthse/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{connect nw length/.style={connect nw=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n length/.style ={connect n =true, keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne length/.style={connect ne=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw length/.style={connect sw=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s length/.style ={connect s =true, keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se length/.style={connect se=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw < length/.style={connect nw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n < length/.style ={connect n <=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne < length/.style={connect ne <=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw < length/.style={connect sw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s < length/.style ={connect s <=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se < length/.style={connect se <=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw > length/.style={connect nw >=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n > length/.style ={connect n >=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne > length/.style={connect ne >=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw > length/.style={connect sw >=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s > length/.style ={connect s >=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se > length/.style={connect se >=true, keylengthse={#1}}}

% Shapes
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{morphism}
{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \anchorborder{\centerpoint}
    \saveddimen\savedlengthnw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthnw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthn
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthn}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthne
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthne}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthsw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthsw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengths
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengths}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthse
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthse}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\overallwidth
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/width}{\minwidth}
        \pgf@x=\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\minwidth
            \pgf@x=\minwidth
        \fi
    }
    \savedanchor{\upperrightcorner}
    {
        \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@y by -.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{north}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{north east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by 5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by -5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{north west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{connect nw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthnw
    }
    \anchor{connect ne}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthne
    }
    \anchor{connect sw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthsw
    }
    \anchor{connect se}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthse
    }
    \anchor{connect n}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthn
    }
    \anchor{connect s}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengths
    }
    \anchor{south east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{text}
    {
        \upperrightcorner
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \backgroundpath
    {
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
        \begin{scope}
                \ifhflip
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifhvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {0.5*\overallwidth+5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \ifwedge
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 15pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \else
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 5pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \fi
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathclose
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \end{scope}
        \ifconnectnw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectne
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectsw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectse
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectn
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnects
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectnwf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
        \fi
        \ifconnectswf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectsef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnf
        \draw [forward arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
    \fi
    \ifconnectsf
        \draw [forward arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
            to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnwr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
    \fi
    \ifconnectner
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
    \fi
    \ifconnectswr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
            to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectser
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
            to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
    \ifconnectnr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
            to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
    \fi
    \ifconnectsr
        \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
            to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
    \fi
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [whitedot] (d0) at (4, 8) {$\alpha$};
  \node [whitedot] (d1) at (2, 4) {$\beta$};
  \node [whitedot] (d2) at (6, 4) {$\gamma$};
  \draw (0,.01) to[out=0, in=180] (8,.01);
  \draw (d0.center) to[out=180, in=-90] (0,12);
  \draw (d0.center) to[out=0, in=-90] (8, 12);
  \draw (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=0] (d1.center);
  \draw (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=180] (d2.center);
  \draw (d1.center) to[out=180, in=90] (0, 0);
  \draw (d1.center) to[out=0, in=90] (4,0);
  \draw (d2.center) to[out=180, in=90] (4, 0);
  \draw (d2.center) to[out=0, in=90] (8, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

I would like to be able to label the negative spaces with uppercase letters A-F, and the edges with lowercase letters f-m:

[image]

I could see just creating 14 additional nodes and labeling them as needed, but I was hoping there was an existing functionality or one that could be added easily to label the 'empty spaces' and 'edges' of the diagram since I will have to make many diagrams like this one (but more complicated on average).  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You may add a node like this \draw (d0.center) to [out=180, in=-90] node [right] {f} (0,12);

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein I'll try that out, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat simplified way to do it. Let's go through it.

#### Package intended ?

If you don't, you don't need all these:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{freetikz}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
```

If you do, your code should be a bit different, which I'm not going to detail here.

#### Layers

... aren't really needed here. The problem of non-filling nodes is easily solved by changing the order of paths. To do so, it's useful to define some coordinates first.

So the flow is like this:

- define `\coordinate`s
- `\draw` the boundaries AND path-related labels AND remember some `\coordinate`s
- "put the frame"
- putting labels
- labeling the regions
- define and use styles as you go (*refactoring*)

#### Coordinates

To be able to place nodes at these positions later, just do:

```
    % ~~~ coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (d0) at (4, 8);
    \coordinate (d1) at (2, 4);
    \coordinate (d2) at (6, 4);
```

#### The boundaries

Turns out, it's useful to combine a number of actions, while remembering, that `\draw` starts a path, while `;` ends it and everything else in between is placed or executed along this path.

So the most complex construct here, like

```
\draw (d0.center) to[out=180, in=-90] node[posi_1]{f} (0, 12) coordinate (D);
```

comprises:

- drawing `\draw (d0.center) to[out=180, in=-90] (0, 12);`
- placing a `\node` beforehand using some style `node[posi_1]{f}` (kindly notice the missing `\`)
- remembering the final coordinate before ending the path `(0, 12) coordinate (D);`

#### The "frame"

Just to complete the picture: `\draw (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);`

However, you'd preferably do `\draw (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) - cylce;` for a closed path AND remove the line drawn from (A) to (B) at the bottom elsewhere from your code.

#### Putting filled nodes for alpha etc.

That works now, because you do it late while recalling the coordinates:

```
    % ~~~ putting labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [whitedot] at (d0) {$\alpha$};
    \node [whitedot] at (d1) {$\beta$};
    \node [whitedot] at (d2) {$\gamma$};
```

#### Labeling the regions

Straight forward:

```
    % ~~~ regions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[reg] at (4  ,10  ) {A};
    \node[reg] at (1.5, 7  ) {B};
    \node[reg] at (6.5, 7  ) {C};
    \node[reg] at (4  , 4.3) {D};
    \node[reg] at (2  , 2  ) {E};
    \node[reg] at (6  , 2  ) {F};
```

#### Styles

You can put them at the beginning, like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[                            % styles
    dot/.style={circle, 
                draw=black, fill=black!25,
                inner sep=.4ex, line width=0.7},
    whitedot/.style={dot, fill=white},
    %
    posi_1/.style={yshift= 3mm,pos=0.3 },       % for f and g
    posi_2/.style={xshift=-3mm,pos=0.35},       % for h, j and l
    posi_3/.style={xshift=+3mm,pos=0.35},       % for i, k and m
    reg/.style={font={\huge\bfseries}},         % for the regions
]
```

and change everything in one place only. E.g. you can finetune the relative postions of a, b, ... along their pathes via `pos=...`.

The thickness defined elsewhere didn't make too much sense, as it affects only the circles in your posted code, as far as I can see.

#### BTW

`(d0.center)` is somewhat redundant:

- if it's a `\node`, the default anchor is at the nodes center
- if it's a `\coordinate` by it's very definition it has no size, i.e. an `anchor=north` coincides with `anchor=center`

So `(d0)` etc. will suffice here.

---

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\def\thickness{2.7pt}% not the best way to do it % useless

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[                            % styles
    dot/.style={circle, 
                draw=black, fill=black!25,
                inner sep=.4ex, line width=0.7},
    whitedot/.style={dot, fill=white},
    %
    posi_1/.style={yshift= 3mm,pos=0.3 },       % for f and g
    posi_2/.style={xshift=-3mm,pos=0.35},       % for h, j and l
    posi_3/.style={xshift=+3mm,pos=0.35},       % for i, k and m
    reg/.style={font={\huge\bfseries}},         % for the regions
]
    % ~~~ coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (d0) at (4, 8);
    \coordinate (d1) at (2, 4);
    \coordinate (d2) at (6, 4);
    
    % ~~~ drawing the boundaries AND path-related labels ~~~~~~
    \draw (0,.01)     to[out=  0, in=180]                 (8,.01);
    \draw (d0.center) to[out=180, in=-90] node[posi_1]{f} (0, 12) coordinate (D);
    \draw (d0.center) to[out=  0, in=-90] node[posi_1]{g} (8, 12) coordinate (C);
    \draw (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=  0] node[posi_2]{h} (d1.center);
    \draw (d0.center) to[out=-90, in=180] node[posi_3]{i} (d2.center);
    \draw (d1.center) to[out=180, in= 90] node[posi_2]{j} (0, 0) coordinate (A);
    \draw (d1.center) to[out=  0, in= 90] node[posi_3]{k} (4,0);
    \draw (d2.center) to[out=180, in= 90] node[posi_2]{l} (4, 0);
    \draw (d2.center) to[out=  0, in= 90] node[posi_3]{m} (8, 0) coordinate (B);
    % ~~~ "frame" ~~~
    \draw (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);
    
    % ~~~ putting labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [whitedot] at (d0) {$\alpha$};
    \node [whitedot] at (d1) {$\beta$};
    \node [whitedot] at (d2) {$\gamma$};
    % ~~~ retions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[reg] at (4  ,10  ) {A};
    \node[reg] at (1.5, 7  ) {B};
    \node[reg] at (6.5, 7  ) {C};
    \node[reg] at (4  , 4.3) {D};
    \node[reg] at (2  , 2  ) {E};
    \node[reg] at (6  , 2  ) {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```